# Creating for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have four similar tables but just for different segments. I need to add three variables to each table using SQL queries. But the queries are identical except for the table name in the query. Is there a smarter way like a for loop to make the code simpler?

I have four tables  "combine", "desktop", "pWeb", "tWeb". And I want to add t1, t2, and t3 variables into these tables as below.

```
combine = sqldf("select region_count, visitor_count, treatment_group, local_dt, case when local_dt >= '2016-03-19' and local_dt<'2016-05-19' then 0 when local_dt>='2016-05-19' then 1 end as t2 
                from combine group by region_count, visitor_count, treatment_group, local_dt, case when local_dt >= '2016-03-19' and local_dt<'2016-05-19' then 0 when local_dt>='2016-05-19' then 1 end")
combine = sqldf("select region_count, visitor_count, treatment_group, local_dt, t2 ,case when treatment_group =  'Control' then 0 when treatment_group = 'Test' then 1 end as t3 
       from combine group by region_count, visitor_count, treatment_group, local_dt,t2,case when treatment_group =  'Control' then 0 when treatment_group = 'Test' then 1 end")
combine = sqldf("select region_count, visitor_count, treatment_group, local_dt, t2,t3 ,case when t2 =  1 and t3 =1 then 1 else 0 end as t1 
       from combine group by region_count, visitor_count, treatment_group, local_dt,t2,t3,case when t2 =  1 and t3 =1 then 1 else 0 end")
```

Comment: Why do you have case statements in each query after group by command?

Comment: You could use for loop and then paste different dataset inside the sqldf function.